# CSS Absolute Positioning

Tags: css

Theory question:

Where should an absolutely positioned element start within it's positioned parent? At its border edge, or its padding offset? Safari seems to ignore the parent's padding when absolutely positioning a child, but firefox and IE seem to take the padding into account and start from that offset.

Thanks

Comment: This [link](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) should help you out with positioning and how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-offset things will take padding into account.  If you have non-auto offsets, then those are measured from the boundary between the padding and the border.

Comment: Dumb question, what's an "auto-offset"?  Ie what css attribute sets the "offset"?

Answer (score 0):

The following appears to come out the same in all the browser. In IE9. FF4.01, GG11, AF5 and Opera 11. In the absence of top, bottom, right or left properties, the child element when absolutely positioned, starts after the padding applied. i.e., the top of the child element start from the bottom of the padding and the left of the child element starts after the left padding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Template</title>
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="outer">

<div class="inner">
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
div.outer
    {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #38EAFF;
    margin: 50px;
    padding: 25px;
    }


div.inner
    {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    outline: 1px solid green;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    }
```

I dont see Safari ignoring the parent's apdding here?

Comment: Indeed, this test case behaves consistently and as expected. I must have some other influencing element that I'm missing that's creating my funk. I'll reexamine and repost if I can't figure. Thanks for taking the time.